# System.IO.File.WriteAllText will not write to a file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've created a method so that when a button (butCommit) is clicked, the value of a textbox is taken and stored into a string. That string is then written to a .txt file using the WriteAllText method. However, when this method is executed, the file is not modified at all.

The button method is working fine, as I have a response.redirect method in there which works every time.
The path for the .txt file is also correct as I have another method which will, on the page load, display the current contents of the .txt file (using the ReadAllText method) and the exact same path that I am using for the WriteAllText method.

Here is the code giving me problems:

```
void butCommit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var path = Server.MapPath(@"~/content.txt");
        string content = txtHomepageContent.Text;
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, content);

        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
    }
```

I'll repeat again: The above method is initialized and works fine with the Response.Redirect method, just not the WriteAllText method.

EDIT For more clarity:

The purpose of this is to display a message on the home page of a site. That message is required to be stored in a .txt file which is on the server (named content.txt). In the ControlPanel.aspx page, the user needs to be able to change the context of the text file using a text box. Preferably they are also able to view what is currently in content.txt using the same text box.

The code I have for the viewing bit is this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var path = Server.MapPath(@"~/content.txt");
    string content = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);
    txtHomepageContent.Text = content;
}
```

This specifies "path" as the path to content.txt, then specifies "content" as a string containing content.txt's data. After that it places "content" into the textbox txtHomepageContent. This is also the text box used to input the new data for content.txt.

It seems if I remove the above section of code, I am able to write to the text file now with no problems, however I of course am unable to view what is in there first. If I leave the above code chunk in, then whatever I write in the textbox is ignored, and the original text is submitted back into the content.txt, resulting in no changes.

I do understand there are easier ways of doing this such as storing in a database, but the requirements are for it to be in a .txt file.

Comment: That method will do exactly what its documentation claims it will. The problem must be somewhere else. Add breakpoints, go debugging.

Comment: WriteAllText will overwrite the file, so if you call it multiple times with the same string, it will appear unchanged. Did you want AppendAllText?

Comment: Have you stepped through the code to verify that the 'path' reference actually points to the location you think it does? If I was to guess the file is being written fine, just not to the location you think it is.

Comment: @MaxHampton I changed it to AppendAllText but now every time I click the button, whatever is already in the .txt file doubles, so "test test" goes to "test test test test".

Comment: @user469104 The path that I am reading from and the path that I am writing to are the same, and I can read the data from the file fine.

Comment: @Frayt So the WriteAllText was most likely working, but just overwriting the file with the same text that was read with ReadAllText.

Comment: @Frayt you are not making it very easy for us to help you. Go ahead and state what you are expecting to happen and what is actually happening. It seems like the AppenAllText does exactly what it should do. If txtHomePageContent.Text has the value "test test" and you click the commit button twice, it would result in the file containing the text "test test" twice...

Comment: Again, put breakpoints in your page and follow the program flow. It sounds like something is happening in Page_Load. And perhaps consider not writing a CMS in WebForms, but that's up to you.

Comment: @MaxHampton Looks like you're right. I removed the method from Page_Load which read the file and put it in the textbox, and now I can write to the file fine. Is there any workaround for this other than putting the current text in a different textbox?

Comment: I'm not clear on what you need to work around. Could you edit your post with more detail, and expected behavior?

Comment: @MaxHampton Edited, hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use the `Page_Init` event handler instead of `Page_Load` to initialize your text box (since submitted postback values will load between the Init and Load events, effectively overwriting the text box value with what was submitted), or if you want to stay with `Page_Load`, check whether there is a postback first:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    if (this.Page.IsPostBack)
       return;

    var path = Server.MapPath(@"~/content.txt");
    string content = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);
    txtHomepageContent.Text = content;
}
```